# Wrap String.Join method

Tags: c#, linq, generics, ienumerable

I created a program like this which works fine:

```
using System;
class Program {
   static string S(string[] a) => String.Join(',', a);
   static void Main() {
      string[] a = {"May", "June", "July"};
      Console.WriteLine(S(a));
   }
}
```

However if I change the program a little:

```
using System.Linq;
using System;
class Program {
   static string S(string[] a) => String.Join(',', a);
   static void Main() {
      string[] a = {"May", "June", "July"};
      var a2 = a.Skip(1);
      Console.WriteLine(S(a2));
   }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'
```

I then tried to change function to this:

```
static string S<T>(T a) => String.Join(',', a);
```

but I just get this output:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+ListPartition`1[System.String]
```

what is the correct way to write this function, so that is accepts both types?

Comment: Just need to add ToArray() : String.Join(',', a.ToArray())

Comment: Or change the method to take a `IEnumerable<string>` as there is an overload of `string.Join` that will handle that.

Comment: @jdweng I think you mean `S(a2.ToArray())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array of strings is `IEnumerable<string>` and `String.Join` can take an IEnumerable of string so.

```
static string S(IEnumerable<string> a) => String.Join(',', a);
```

Will accept both a string array and the result of `Skip(1)`

```
static string S(IEnumerable<string> a) => String.Join(',', a);
public static void Main()
{
    string[] a = {"May", "June", "July"};
    Console.WriteLine(S(a));
    var a2 = a.Skip(1);
    Console.WriteLine(S(a2));
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0MOjL5

If you had intended to support more than just strings (eg an array/enumerable of ints) then this can be changed to:

```
static string S<T>(IEnumerable<T> a) => String.Join(',', a);
```

and called with an array of any type which will `ToString` to something meaningful

```
Console.WriteLine(S(new[]{ 1, 2, 3})); // "1,2,3"
```

Note there is no need to specify the type `T` when calling it - that is inferred.

Answer (score -2):

Another option, encode to JSON:

```
using C = System.Console;
using J = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer;
using System.Linq;

class Program {
   static void Main() {
      string[] a = {"May", "June", "July"};
      var a2 = a.Skip(1);
      C.WriteLine(J.Serialize(a) + J.Serialize(a2));
   }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer